# How to create a list of strings in python from two "array.flatten()"-ed lists

Tags: python, arrays, string, list

I'm looking to create the following list in python:

```
list = ["pix420_615", "pix421_615", ... , "pix425_620"]
```

N.B. Where the list is a list of strings, not values.

From the following two lists:

```
x= [420, 421, 422, 423, 424, 425, 420, 421, 422, 423, 424, 425, 420, 421, 422, 423, 424, 425,
 420, 421, 422, 423, 424, 425, 420, 421, 422, 423, 424, 425, 420, 421, 422, 423, 424, 425]

y= [615, 615, 615, 615, 615, 615, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 617, 617, 617, 617, 617, 617,
 618, 618, 618, 618, 618, 618, 619, 619, 619, 619, 619, 619, 620, 620, 620, 620, 620, 620]
```

I was wondering how I would go about doing this, and maintain the consistency of corresponding array values...?

Comment: Do you mean `list = ['pix420_615', 'pix421_615', ...]` where each element is a string? If not, what are the values `pix420_615`, etc.?

Comment: @smarx Yeh, where each element is just a string created from adding pix to the x and y arrays in sequential order...

Comment: quite simply: `map(lambda t: 'pix%s_%s' % t, zip(x, y))` (or, if you don't like map: `['pix%s_%s' % t for t in zip(x, y)]`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick. `zip` is the nicest way to do this sort of thing:

```
x = [420, 421, 422, 423, 424, 425, 420, 421, 422, 423, 424, 425, 420, 421, 422, 423, 424, 425, 420, 421, 422, 423, 424, 425, 420, 421, 422, 423, 424, 425, 420, 421, 422, 423, 424, 425]

y = [615, 615, 615, 615, 615, 615, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 617, 617, 617, 617, 617, 617, 618, 618, 618, 618, 618, 618, 619, 619, 619, 619, 619, 619, 620, 620, 620, 620, 620, 620]

z = ['pix{}_{}'.format(a, b) for a, b in zip(x, y)]

print(z)

# Output:
# ['pix420_615', 'pix421_615', 'pix422_615', 'pix423_615', 'pix424_615', 'pix425_615', 'pix420_616', 'pix421_616', 'pix422_616', 'pix423_616', 'pix424_616', 'pix425_616', 'pix420_617', 'pix421_617', 'pix422_617', 'pix423_617', 'pix424_617', 'pix425_617', 'pix420_618', 'pix421_618', 'pix422_618', 'pix423_618', 'pix424_618', 'pix425_618', 'pix420_619', 'pix421_619', 'pix422_619', 'pix423_619', 'pix424_619', 'pix425_619', 'pix420_620', 'pix421_620', 'pix422_620', 'pix423_620', 'pix424_620', 'pix425_620']
```

Answer (score 2):

From your lists,

```
map(lambda t: 'pix%s_%s' % t, zip(x, y))
```

or

```
['pix%s_%s' % t for t in zip(x, y)]
```

However, I notice that the first list is basically `[420, ..., 425]`, and the second one is `[615, ...]`, which result in `zip(x, y)` representing the product of `range(420, 426)` and `range(620, 626)`.

You can simplify all that by:

```
from itertools import product

['pix%s_%s' % (y, x) for x, y in product(range(615, 621), range(420, 426))]
```

Comment: One *tiny* nit-pick. The small optimization benefit from using `map` over a list comprehension is lost [when using `lambda`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1247490/1555990). I do like the `itertools.product` solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

use `map` function

```
map(lambda a, b: 'pix{0}_{1}'.format(a,b), x, y)
```